# What directories does root own in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, xubuntu, directory, root

Can I get a list of root directories that Ubuntu Server 14.04 uses to boot with?
What are the root owned Folders and Files?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need this for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Almost all of them. Because that's what being superuser means.

Comment: These are two completely different questions. The list of directories containing files needed during boot has nothing to do with the list of directories owned by root. The only thing they have in common is that one is a subset of the other (all the needed directories are owned by root, but not all directories owned by root are needed during boot). Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo find / -type d -user root
```

gives you the list of all directories, owned by root. You might restrict the searching depth with -maxdepth:

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 3 -type d -user root
```

You need sudo, because for some directory, you don't have read permissions, and they contain subsequent folders.

After seeing the list, I guess you will abstain from seeing the list of files.

For booting, the files used are in /boot, then many configuration files in /etc then there are important directories for executables. My system reports the root PATH as being: 
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

but I don't understand the presence of the two games folders.

Other important directories are

```
/dev
/proc 
/root
/run
/serv
/sys
/var
```

But of course, while initializing the system, the /mnt and /cdrom dir get touched (if available), libraries are used and resources from all over the place, except from the /home folder and it's subfolders.